# Standard information-theoretic lower bound?

Tags: information-theory, lower-bounds

There should be a simple argument, but I'm struggling to see it.

Suppose Alice has a string $x \in \{0, 1\}^n$ and sends a message $s = s(x)$ to Bob. And suppose that given $s$, Bob can reconstruct *each* bit of $x$ with probability $2/3$ (say). (Note that this is weaker than the claim "with probability $2/3$, Bob can recover the entire string $x$." A clean proof of this case would be appreciated too.)

Then we should be able to conclude $|s| = \Omega(n)$, and this seems obvious, but can someone formalize this for me?

Comment: Bob, given $s(x)$, can recover each bit of $x$ with probability $2/3$. I want to conclude that $|s(x)| = \Omega(|x|)$.

Comment: I want to prove that Alice must send at least $\Omega(|x|)$ bits in order for Bob to recover each bit of $x$ with probability $2/3$. If Alice sends nothing, then I don't see how Bob can recover anything...

Comment: Try the following: the mutual information between $x$ and $s$ is at least $nh(2/3) = \Omega(n)$, and since $I(x;s) \leq H(s) \leq |s|$, we must have $|s| = \Omega(n)$.

Comment: Your premise is expressed rather informally. Can you make it more precise?

Comment: The closest thing I can find is the one-way gap-Hamming problem. I want to show that any one-way communication protocol that allows Bob to recover each bit with probability $2/3$ requires $\Omega(n)$ bits. Unfortunately, I don't see how this fits in the standard notions of communication complexity. Again, even a proof of the weaker claim would be appreciated, so I would at least know what to search.

Comment: When proving a lower bound, it’s important to state the problem clearly. That’s not the case at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I understand your question this way:

> Assume Alice has some $X\in\{0,1\}^n$. Alice encodes (compresses) $X$ into $s = s(X)$, where $|s|\le n$. Bob decodes $s$ to obtain $X'=dec(s)$. 
>   Show that unless $|s|=\Omega(n)$ it cannot hold that Hamming$(X,X') < n/3$.

If this is what you meant, then this follows from the fact that most strings cannot be compressed. Assume that for any $X$, $|s(X)|=o(n)$. Note that there are at most $2^{|s|}\ll 2^n$ such strings. More accurately, $2^{|s|} / 2^n \to_{n\to\infty} 0$.

Then, for each possible $s$ construct $dec(s)$ and define $Y_s$ to be a Hamming ball of radius $n/3$ centered at $dec(s)$. Verify that $|Y_s| = \sum_{d=0}^{n/3}\binom{n}{d} < 2^{n\cdot h(1/3)}$, with $h(\cdot)$ the binary entropy function.
Thus $\left|\bigcup_s |Y_s|\right| \le 2^{o(n)}2^{0.92n} \ll 2^n$. This means that there exists a string $X$ not covered by the $Y_s$ for any $s$, i.e., not within a Hamming-distance of $n/3$ from any of the decoding of any $s$.

---

If this is not what you meant, you will have to formulate your statement in a proper way. For instance, you say "with probability 2/3", but there is no probability space defined in your statement, etc.